# MasterNotDiscoveredException in Elastic Search when creating an index

Tags: elasticsearch

I've followed the simple tutorial to install elastic-search on a clean debian lenny machine:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2010/07/02/setting-up-elasticsearch-on-debian.html

However, when trying to create index with mapping:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/searchdata" -d @index.json
```

I get this error:

```
{"error":"MasterNotDiscoveredException[]","status":500}
```

I've used the `index.json` on another instance of ES, so I know that it works. I'm assuming I'm missing something the the ES config file. currently I have this:

```
cluster:
  name:   MyCluster

network:
  host:   _eth0_
```

As docs are pretty scarce for ES, I thought I'd see if anyone can lead me to a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't call the example configuration file “scarce”: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/config/elasticsearch.yml

Comment: what's the output when trying start elastic search.  I think your problem might be the network host.  If ES starts right, you'll see in the output that it elected a master.

Comment: @AndyPryor, I've messed with it so much, I actually can't recreate the issue. I've just gone back to an old instance that I was hoping to clean up and am using that. I've been really unsuccessful trying to get elastic-search installed on debian lenny - except for the very first time I tried (and I don't remember what tutorial I used for that). I've even tried installing on Amazon EC2 and couldn't get that to work correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure the issue, but a clean install of the OS fixed it.